# Difference between bitwise inclusive or and exclusive or in java

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators

```
public class Operators {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int a = 12;

    System.out.println("Bitwise AND:"+(12&12));
    System.out.println("Bitwise inclusive OR:"+(12|12));
    System.out.println("Bitwise exclusive OR:"+(12^12));

    }
}

OUTPUT:

Bitwise AND:12
Bitwise inclusive OR:12
Bitwise exclusive OR:0
```

I understand first two, but not the third.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

XOR tells whether each bit is different.

1 XOR 1 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
0 XOR 0 = 0

In other words "either but not both"

0011 XOR 0101 = 0110

Answer (score 11):

BITWISE INCLUSIVE OR (|) means normal **or** operation ,

BITWISEE ExCLUSIVE OR (^) means **xor** operation

Answer (score 3):

Third one is an XOR operation (Xclusive-OR)

It says, OR should be exclusively:
where similar will be False(0)
and dissimilar will be True(1).

So 12 in binary would be 1100

So, perform bitwise XOR here:

```
  1 1 0 0
  1 1 0 0
---------
  0 0 0 0
---------
```

Every column has same digit, either both are 1's or both are 0's
XOR says, both should be different. Hence all zeros

Answer (score 1):

Exclusive or (`XOR`) is defined as:

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

That is, it is `0` when two values are the same, `1` if they are different.

So, given two bit patterns which are exactly equal, each XORed bit will evaluate to `0`, as each bit will either have `1` in both positions, or `0` in both positions.