# XOR being used to compare longs in Random class?

Tags: java, long-integer, xor, boolean-operations

I decompiled the `Random` class using IntelliJ IDEA and I found this line:

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}
```

I am confused because I thought the `^` symbol was an XOR that only compared two `boolean` values. The two methods, `seedUniquifier()`, and `System.nanoTime()` both return `long` values.

```
private static long seedUniquifier() {
    long var0;
    long var2;
    do {
        var0 = seedUniquifier.get();
        var2 = var0 * 181783497276652981L;
    } while(!seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(var0, var2));

    return var2;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651465/bitwise-xor-java-long

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Link is not related.

Comment: @chris13524 There's no need to decompile the Java standard library classes, because the source code is publicly available. And that means you'll get nice variable names instead of `var0`, etc.

Comment: In particular, the relevant source code is online [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java#Random.<init>()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` (XOR) operator in Java applies to either two `boolean`s, two `int`s, or two `long`s, giving back the same type as a result.

I assume you know how XOR works on two Boolean values, which can be true or false.

When XOR is applied to two integers, the XOR is applied separately to each bit. For example:

```
0xC5 = 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
0xF9 = 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
---------------------- XOR
0x3C = 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`^`, just like `&` and `|` is not only a boolean operator in Java, but also an integer bitwise operator as you can see in the [Java Language Specification, §15.22.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1).

Answer (score 1):

The `^` operator is not exactly exclusive or (XOR). It is a bitwise exclusive or. Borrowing from [this related answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16642810/3224483), consider 0011 ^ 0100. If we perform a bitwise XOR, we get:

- 1 XOR 1 = 0
- 1 XOR 0 = 1
- 0 XOR 1 = 1
- 0 XOR 0 = 0

Thus, the bitwise XOR of 0011 and 0101 equals 0110.

The result of `^` takes on the same type as the inputs. A bitwise XOR of two booleans results in a boolean, two longs result in a long, etc.

Try not to think of `^` as behaving differently for booleans. A boolean is really just one bit (on or off), and so a bitwise XOR results in a single bit. The only difference is the type of the output.